# New TypeScript code is not generating new JavaScript code

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm

I just wrote a new TypeScript method and wanted to debug but it was not in the source map, neither here in the IDE nor in Chrome Dev Tools.

How should I get it to rebuild and generate the new JavaScript to match its TypeScript?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the generated JavaScript file?

Comment: @JosuGoñi : Ok looks like it works as is BUT? it is EXTREMELY slow. Took it more than 5 minutes to built the file. And it is a HelloWorld file literally.

Comment: do you use the built-in compiler to generate js files (**Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**, **Recompile on changes**?), or some other tools (webpack, gulp/grunt, etc.) are used?

Comment: @lena I used the Build menu button in IntelliJ IDE

Comment: you can't use *Build* menu to run the built-in compiler. You need to either enable **Recompile on changes** to trigger the compilation on file change, or run it explicitly using the *Compile* button in Typescript tool window

Answer (score 1):

you can't use **Build** main menu to run the built-in compiler. You need to either enable **Recompile on changes** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript** to trigger the compilation on file change or run it explicitly using the **Compile** button in the **Typescript** tool window.

See the *Recompile on changes* option description in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.1/settings-languages-typescript.html:

```
When this checkbox is selected, the compiler "wakes up" upon any change to a TypeScript file.

When this checkbox is cleared, the compiler ignores changes to TypeScript files. To re-activate the compiler, open the TypeScript Tool Window (View | Tool Windows | TypeScript), click icon_ts_compile_all on the toolbar, and choose the compilation scope from the list:
If you have not opened the TypeScript tool window yet and it is not available from the View menu, choose Help | Find Action, then find and launch the TypeScript Compile All action from the list.
```